# No puedo llamar una imagen desde el CSS

Tags: html, css

Por que no puedo llamar una imagen desde el css cuando el archivo css lo tengo dentro de una carpeta? (Lo intente meter en una carpeta para ordenar) .

Estoy intentando llamar a una imagen que tengo en una carpeta IMG pero no me deja, pero cuando tengo el archivo css "desordenado" sin estar en ninguna carpeta me deja llamarlo sin problema?

Lo estoy tratando de llamar de la siguiente manera.

```css
.imagen-fondo{
background:url(https://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/600x375/photos.demandstudios.com/getty/article/147/118/71031242.jpg);
height:500px;
width:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagen-fondo">

</div>
```

Comment: como estas incluyendo tu archivo css en el .html? la ruta es correcta?

Comment: Si, la ruta es correcta lo hago a traves del <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"> Me toma todo el css menos las imagenes que hago con esa llamada

Comment: como son las estruturas de las carpetas

Comment: Pues, la estructura de las carpetas es la siguiente: Carpeta principal contiene (Index.html, Img(Es una carpeta) dentro de img tengo dos carpetas mas (Brand y blog), tengo otra carpeta (CSS) que solo contiene el archivo css y por ultimo Js que contiene solamente el archivo Javascript de resto no tengo mas nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu archivo css y tu imagen no comparten el mismo directorio debes colocar la instrucción correcta para enlazar la imagen:

Entonces, tu archivo "styles.css" está en la carpeta "css", y tu archivo "fondo.jpg" está en la carpeta "img", entonces al enlazar la imagen de fondo desde el archivo "styles.css" debes retroceder al root para poder acceder a la carpeta "img", esto lo haces colocando "../" al inicio de la ruta de tu imagen:

```
background: url("../img/fondo.jpg");
```

Espero te sirva.
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

¿Estás llamando a la imagen por link?
Cuando llamas una imagen que está alojada en tu computadora asegúrate de indicar la subcarpeta donde se encuentra. Es decir, si creas una carpeta llamada "img". Por ejemplo estableces el *src* como "img/example.jpg".

Comment: Le establezco la ruta donde se encuentra la imagen asi " background: url(img/fondo1.jpg) no-repeat center; " Pero aun asi sigue sin darme la imagen, solo me deja colocarla cuando tengo el archivo css solo sin estar en ninguna carpeta

Comment: Mejor llama a la imagen desde HTML y no desde Css.
<img src="http://www.exampleimagehost.com/my-cute-dog.jpg">